# SQL analogue of Pandas diff() function (1st discrete difference) [LAG function]

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, difference

I am looking for a way to write a SQL query that would apply a 1st discrete difference to the original series. This is ridiculously easy in Python by using Pandas's [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

df["diff_A"]=df["A"].diff()
df["diff_B"]=df["B"].diff()

print(df)
```

My desired output is demonstrated in `"diff_A"` and `"diff_B"` columns:

```
    A   B  diff_A  diff_B
0  36  14     NaN     NaN
1  32  13    -4.0    -1.0
2  31  87    -1.0    74.0
3  58  88    27.0     1.0
4  44  34   -14.0   -54.0
5   2  43   -42.0     9.0
6  15  94    13.0    51.0
7  46  74    31.0   -20.0
8  60   9    14.0   -65.0
9  43  57   -17.0    48.0
```

I use Oracle, but I definitely prefer a clean ANSI solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use analytic [LAG](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652) function:

```
with v as (
  select rowid as rn, a, b from tab
)
select
  a, b,
  a - lag(a, 1) over(order by rn) as diff_a,
  b - lag(b, 1) over(order by rn) as diff_b
from v
order by rn;
```

PS it would be much better to use a real column (like date) for ordering, because [`rowid` can be changed](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=when-can-a-rowid-change).

For example:

```
select
  a, b,
  a - lag(a, 1) over(order by inserted) as diff_a,
  b - lag(b, 1) over(order by inserted) as diff_b
from tab;
```

[@MatBailie has posted a very good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164751/pandas-diff-1st-discrete-difference-in-sql/48164931?noredirect=1#comment83310061_48164931):

> Data-sets in SQL are un-ordered. For deterministic results in LAG()
>   always use a sufficient ORDER BY clause. (If no such field exists, one
>   should be created when/before the data in inserted in to a SQL data
>   set. The un-ordered nature of a SQL data set allows massive numbers of
>   scalability options and optimisation options to be available.)

[SQL Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38715/1)

PS [Windowing functions were added to the ANSI/ISO Standard SQL:2003 and then extended in ANSI/ISO Standard SQL:2008. Microsoft was late to this game. DB2, Oracle, Sybase, PostgreSQL and other products have had full implementations for years. SQL Server did not catch up until SQL 2012.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/)

Comment: And ordering by original series is not neccessary desired action (e.g. it doesnt produce a right result in the test example). One should order by for example by date, IIUC :)

Comment: @MarjanModerc, AFAIK, it's part of ANSI SQL 99 standard

Comment: @MarjanModerc, there is no `date` column in your sample data set ;-)

Comment: Good point, but still, ordering is unnecessary part of a step that in fact corrupts the calculation, am I right? Now original a and lagged a are inconsistant, right?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to `(order by rowid)` if the insertion order is chronological

Comment: Thank you @MaxU for a great and quick answer! Now I love Python even more! :D

Comment: Data-sets in SQL are un-ordered.  For deterministic results in `LAG()` ***always*** use a sufficient `ORDER BY` clause.  *(If no such field exists, one should be created when/before the data in inserted in to a SQL data set.  The un-ordered nature of a SQL data set allows massive numbers of scalability options and optimisation options to be available.)*

Comment: @Spade, good point! I misunderstood you first - i thout that your proposal would be to use `ORDER BY rowid` inside of analytic functions. I've fixed it now...

Comment: @spade Only if extreme care as been taken at INSERT time, and then this precludes future corrections.  Essentially, from a robustness / engineering perspective;  don't do it.  If there aren't sufficient columns to be referenced by an ORDER BY clause, the data is insufficient for its purposes and that property of the data should be corrected as quite a high priority. *(All other options **will** eventually come back to bite you in the end.)*

Comment: Agreed, but that problem affects the given solution as well. I added an answer and I am questioning why one is required to write the longer form as seen in this solution.

Comment: @Spade I agree.  I'm only commenting so verbosely in an attempt to communicate to the OP that they ***really*** should add an additional column to their SQL Table.  Pandas uses implicitly ordered data-sets, positions can be changed, individual rows can be referenced by position, etc.  SQL adopts a more flexible approach allowing a single data-set to be addressed with multiple different orders, but the ***OP*** is responsible for providing the fields necessary to assert a deterministic order.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this answer just because I was able to replicate the results in an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc514/2) following the comments in the accepted answer. Besides `rowid` changing after the fact, is there a valid argument why this simpler answer does not work.

```
select
  a, b,
  a - lag(a, 1) over(order by rowid) as diff_a,
  b - lag(b, 1) over(order by rowid) as diff_b
from tab;
```

Comment: I had a stupid syntax error when i tested it and i've misunderstood the error from SQL Fiddle... It gave me `ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here` instead of `table or view does not exist`:(